# How to call a destructor

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I know destructors are called by the garbage collector (GC) when objects are no longer used.

But how can I call the destructor through C# code?

If possible please give some basic example for understanding.

Comment: Why do you think you need to call the destructor?

Comment: You almost certainly don't need to *have* a finalizer (C# doesn't have destructors, only finalizers), let alone manually calling it.  You almost certainly should only have a `Dispose` method, and you *should* be manually calling *that*.

Comment: The other option is to wrap it in a `using` statement so it should auto-dispose

Answer (score 22):

You don't call the destructor in .NET.
The managed heap is handled by the [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) and the CLR only.

You can, however, define a destructor to a class. The destructor would be called once the object gets collected by the GC.

```
class Foo
    {
        public Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Constructed");
        }

        ~Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Destructed");
        }
    }
```

Take notice that the destructor doesn't (and can't) have a public modifier in-front of it. It's sort of a hint that you can't explicitly call the destructor of an object.

Answer (score -4):

You can look at the [Destructor Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors).

You need to declare a function with same name as the class name but with a leading "~" sign.

Comment: The question is how to call it, not now to define it.